# Better Method for Implementing Search in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, full-text-search

Currently I am using a simple query for Full-Text search in my website and feel it isn't the absolute best solution for my searching needs. While it may meet my needs now, and is relatively easy to setup, I get the feeling that implementing one of the more well known search solutions is probably best. I am expecting this site to grow and have thousands of records in my database.  Therefore, I am curious as to what is considered best practice in the 'searching' community. At the moment I am looking into Lucene.NET, but it seems rather extensive and might be difficult to incorporate at this stage in development. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at ElasticSearch or Solr, which abstract a lot of the complexity of Lucene with a RESTful API and XML configuration.

Lucene.net is not that bad if you want simple search..just try running your data through the StandardAnalyzer and to search use query parse...where Lucene gets more complex quick is with: distributed search, very high volume of data, faceting etc.  I would recommend "Lucene in Action", which is for Java but it covers Lucene 3.0.3, which has API symmetry for the .NET version.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel that Lucene.Net is too much work from the ground and up, I would recommend that you look into RavenDB which has an extremely simple .net client api, and Lucene.Net is built in to the core of it, giving you all the functionality of Lucene.Net.

Wether you need some sort of system storing webpages or file documents RavenDB would fit well. You can save documents containing meta-data and the files as attachments and/or put your web content into it "as is", create indexes and more.